# How many analytic functions are there on a given set

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Consider the set $S=\{0\} \cup \bigl\{\frac{1}{4n+7}:n=1,2,...\bigr\}.$

Then the number of analytic functions which vanishes only on $S$ is

(A) Infinite

(B) $0$

(C) $1$

(D) $2$

I think, the answer is (B).

As, $f\bigl(\frac{1}{4n+7}\bigr)=0$ so the zeros of $f$ are $\bigl\{\frac{1}{4n+7}:n=1,2,...\bigr\}$ which has a limit point $0$ in $S$.

So, by uniqueness theorem $f\equiv 0$. But $f$ vanishes **only** on $S$ , so there are no such function.

Am I right or wrong?

Comment: But $f \equiv 0$ does not vanish only on $S$.

Comment: Ohhh!! So what will be?

Comment: The zero function vanishes everywhere, not just on $S$.  Is there another function $f(z)$ so that $f(z) = 0$ when $z \in S$ and $f(z) \neq 0$ when $z \notin S$?

Comment: How I can show it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that your problem is one of logic! We are talking about he set ${\cal O}$  of analytic functions $f$ with a domain $\Omega\supset S$. You already know that   a function $f\in {\cal O}$ vanishing at all points of $S$ has to be identically $0$. But this implies that there is **no** $f\in {\cal O}$ that is $\ne0$ off $S$. It follows that b) is the correct answer.